# Encrypt user data when they log in with Facebook, Gmail, etc

Tags: java, facebook, encryption

I made a login system. The user can login by:

- using a normal email / password.
- using a service like facebook, gmail, etc.

Now I want to store sensitive information in the database only in encrypted form. First I encrypt data in database by hashed password and when user login in via email and password i can read sensitive data. What should i do when user login from facebook or gmail. What can i do to recognize user and show encrypted data.

Comment: So you have the hashed password, that is used as the encryption key, stored in your database? Well then read it from there, when the user logs in using Facebook or Google ...

Comment: Note that encrypting data with the hashed password does not make much sense since whoever cracks your database will have access to the data as well as the decryption key since the hashed passwords are stored in the db as well. And you as the developer / company owning the database can easily decrypt the data manually as well since you can simply read the decryption key from the db as well.

Comment: Btw: what do you do when a user changes his or her password?

Comment: Ok i can have in database only an user private key which is encypted by user passowrd and this private key encrypt data in my database. I dont have in this case user passwor in database

Comment: i dont store thing to decrypt data. I store encrypt key which can be only decrypt by user password, which I get only when user login